# CartThrob UPS Shipping

Tags: cartthrob, ups-shipping

Is there anyway to see what data is being sent to and returned from UPS?  It appears that the rates I'm getting back are not the rates I'm expecting and would like to see exactly what data UPS is rating for.

Answer (score 1):

I spent about a week writing a very complex bespoke live rates CT plugin recently.

To debug it, I used kint.

- http://raveren.github.io/kint/
- https://github.com/adriangonzales/codeigniter-kint

I installed it via composer and load it at the top of my plugin via:

require '..//composer/vendor/autoload.php';

Then I use Kint::enabled(true); d($some_string); d($some_var);  etc

To debug.

I haven't used UPS but it looks like ~ line 474 is what you need:

```
        $url = "https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate";      
        $data = (string) $access->asXML(). (string) $rating->asXML(); 
        $result =   new SimpleXMLElement($this->EE->cartthrob_shipping_plugins->curl_transaction($url,$data));
```

...so if you:

```
      d($data);
      d($result);
```

...you should get what you need.